# Error: No compatible version found: package-json@'^6.3.0'

Tags: npm, npm-install

I want to install latest version of NPM and running this

```
npm install latest-version
```

I receive

> No compatible version found:package-json'^6.3.0

```
npm WARN package.json copy-descriptor@0.1.1 No readme data.
npm WARN package.json get-value@2.0.6 No readme data.
npm WARN package.json object-copy@0.1.0 No readme data.
npm WARN package.json static-extend@0.1.2 No readme data.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version/-/latest-version-5.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/latest-version/-/latest-version-5.1.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/package-json
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/package-json
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: package-json@'^6.3.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.1.0","1.2.0","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.1.0","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.4.0","3.0.0","3.1.0","4.0.0","4.0.1","5.0.0","6.0.0","6.1.0","6.2.0","6.3.0","6.4.0","6.5.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:709:10)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.js:631:10
npm ERR!     at saved (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "latest-version"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\smuminov
npm ERR! node -v v12.13.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.24
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\smuminov\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

how to resolve this issue?

Current `npm` version - `1.2.24`

Current `node` version - `v12.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of npm.

Use the following command to update npm:

```
npm install npm@latest
```